# generate seperated html based on one json result

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

please look at below html

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="box1"></div>

<div class="ads"></div>

<div id="box2"></div>

<div class="ads"></div>

<div id="box3"></div>

</div>
```

as you can see there's some boxes
and between each two box there's a div with class ads

I need to fill those ads with a list of images

I return a list of images as json using below action

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadAds()
    {
        var adsList = Advertise.GetAdvertise().Select(a => new
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            img = a.img                           
        });
        return Json(adsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function showAds() {              
                var url = '/Home/LoadAds';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: url,
                    success: function (response) {

                          $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                                var htmlcontnet = "";
                                //Need to populate adds here
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (msg) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

how can I generate proper html in success function?

Comment: Is it typo in your original code or typo while you create this question. You are missing `'` in `var url = '/Home/LoadAds;`

Comment: How is each item in array is connected to each ads div ? Will there be always same number of items as the ads divs? If yes, read from the array and add to the div one by one inside the loop.

Comment: @Shyju first json item must replace with first ad div, second with second, and so third with third, and so on ...

Comment: @CodeThing it's typo, I just create an simple example, the real code is different

Comment: @lilifarabari Can you show us your example json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this is your json
`response = {0:"This is Add 1", 1:"This is Add 2"}`

Your code in success handler should be something like this.

```
$.each(response, function (index, item) {
  var htmlcontnet = "";
  $('.ads').eq(index).html(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to create the alternative div dynamically, as you can add any number of ads image, depending on the availability

```js
$(function(){
  showAds();
});

function showAds() {
  var url = '/Home/LoadAds';
  
  // uncomment this line with your orginal url
  //$.get(url, function(response) {
  
  //remove this hardcoded json response
  var response = [{
    Id: 1,
    img: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1078/1078005.png'
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    img: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1078/1078006.png'
  }];
  var imgIndx = 0;
  $(".box").each(function() {
    if (response.length > imgIndx) {
      $(this).after($('<div class="ads"><img src="' + response[imgIndx].img + '" /></div>'));
    }
    imgIndx++;

  });
  //});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```